# Is there a way to block out any and/or all video formats on all browsers?

Tags: router, video, streaming, dd-wrt, blocking

I am trying to block all streaming services for the sake of preserving my high speed satellite Internet, but doing so would require blocking every single website (which has proved difficult enough, providing I have not been able to block any sites with any effect with the toolbox on the GUI on my router)

Effectively my goal is to find a way to prevent video formats from loading on any webpage that one might access.

It would also be nice if I could whitelist certain MAC addresses so that they would be able to load videos when necessary.

any and all solutions or suggestions are definitely welome! I might even be on track with using a different router or downloading another party software if it helps me accomplish this.

.

.

I am using a DD-WRT router DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) mega (SVN revision 21061)

.

I know this is a lot to ask of  a community that may not respond, but I've tired of looking myself and finding nothing of relevance...  thanks for the help!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/210932/disable-streaming-of-video-and-audio-on-a-linksys-wrtp54g-router

Comment: Also this: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/QoS_Filter_Definitions

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into the options available within DD-WRT for managing this?

Comment: i have looked into the simple access restrictions on the DD-WRT GUI and it has failed to block a single thing...

Comment: would that be specified for a browser? my intent is to close this media to all of the network; we have many guests come through on a daily basis and we need to be able to preserve our data for office use only.

Comment: A practical workaround might be to configure the router so that computers not whitelisted are put in a managed pool with very limited bandwidth but a high burst value - this could be tuned so web browsing is responsive but anything which continually uses traffic is throttled down so hard that its not practical to use.   An alternative might be to introduce a captive portal with a tight data allowance.

Answer (score 1):

This should actually be pretty easy. you may have to make separate overlapping policies. a lot of streaming sites automatically redirect to https. you may have to block it on the devices you don't want accessing these sites.

Content filtering - 
Under Access restrictions, Create a new policy.

PC's> edit list of clients> put traffic offenders in here specific by IP or range.

Days = everyday

Time = 24 hours

Catch all P2P protocols = checked

Website Blocking by Keyword & URL = 
[image]

I personally wouldn't recommend squid proxy on a consumer router. I have tried it on three different routers, all with decent CPU power and RAM.
It worked on one, but made traffic come to a crawl, the other two became regularly unstable and would require frequent reboots. I should mention when I installed it on a x86 version on an old PC, it was flawless. YMWV...
I wound up going to PFsense from DD-wrt for this specific task, and never looked back. DD-WRT is great for most home users, but some of the tasks have a steep learning curve. In most cases its easier for a user to just go to a pre-built solution, rather than learning the commands for busy-box etc.

Also, you may want to check this link out. It has instructions for what Davidgo was mentioning.
[Configure DD-WRT to Limit Bandwidth on Devices](https://superuser.com/questions/1292147/configure-dd-wrt-to-limit-bandwidth-on-devices/1301785#1301785)

Comment: Let me know if you still have problems with it. Or even post your settings save file, I could mirror your setup and see if I can figure out why it's not working. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: 1) we tried to use that built in function before anything else, but when it failed to work numerous times, we decided to look for alternatives.  when we could not find the problem with the router's blocking, which you've shown here, we tried several times with slight variations and different browsers (in the case that Opera, which i use, may have been using a redirect which somehow slipped by the router's block)         2) i forgot what 2 was...  3) we have also considered limiting bandwidth on non-whitelisted devices, and frankly that would be our next resort.  hopefully we get this done

Comment: +1 I was actually thinking of pfsense which is open source, works great, and is well-maintained when I made my answer. Will work for most people on a reused 5 or 10 year old computer

Answer (score 0):

You can block mime-types using e.g. *squid* which I believe can be installed on dd-wrt.

Transparent proxies can be slow though.

Comment: this is the most helpful thing that i have read all day.  we're gonna look into it and ill get back to you!